# How to customize the query string in Primefaces

Tags: java, user-interface, primefaces

I am newbee in Primefaces.

In my application, there is a search form which contains 5-10 field. The implemented solution is to check which variable is null and which variable have the value. The list of variable which contains the value is included in the sql query.

Is there any feasible solution in primefaces from where i can customize the query string. The customize query string means the query string contains only those variable which user fills(not the blank one).

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with primefaces though, it more a java question.

Just check if your variables are empty or not, then just add them to the query string and finaly setting the string as your querystring. eg:

```
String s_query = "select * from tbl1 where ";

if(!(searchfield1.equals("")))
{
   s_query = s_query + " searchfield1 = searchfield1";
}
```

Something like that should work